# Mysql week with year provide incorrect results

Tags: mysql

I have one field with date 2016-01-03. And want to get result of year and week in format YEAR-WEEK.

So it should be 53 week of 2015 year (ISO). When I make query it shows as 2016-53 - 53 week of 2016 year (it doesn't exist), but should be 2015-53.

```
SET default_week_format=3;

SELECT CONCAT( YEAR( "2016-01-03") , '-', WEEK( "2016-01-03" ) ) AS `weekAndYear`;
```

Are they any solutions for such problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to rely on [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
select date_format("2016-01-03", "%x-%v") as `weekAndYear`;
2015-53
```

[(fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/40140/0)

From the documentation:

```
%U  Week (00..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 0
%u  Week (00..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 1
%V  Week (01..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 2; used with %X
%v  Week (01..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 3; used with %x
%X  Year for the week where Sunday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %V
%x  Year for the week, where Monday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %v
```

Or, alternatively, parse the result of `YEARWEEK` to stick the dash in the midddle of ear and week.